# Cocoa TDD and singletons

Tags: cocoa, unit-testing, singleton

I'm doing TDD with Cocoa and I wanted to ask - what is the correct way of testing a singleton class? I'm curious about the initialization and retrieval part.

I'm thinking of doing something similar to this:

```
MySingleton *singleton1 = [MySingleton sharedInstance];
MySingleton *singleton2 = [[MySingleton alloc] init];

STAssertEqualObjects(singleton1, singleton2, @"Objects were not equal: %@ and %@", singleton1, singleton2);
```

Anything else I should test for? Should I even try to test the behavior under possible race conditions (test the `@synchronize` statement)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your singleton has no writable state, then you don't have to worry about this at all.

If your singleton has writable state, then it probably shouldn't be a singleton at all.

Comment: OMG, J.B. Rainsberger answered my question \o/ I can die happy now.

Comment: Wonderful compliment or highly advanced trolling? :)

Comment: I've been to two of your speeches in Agile Tour in Lithuania (Vilnius and Kaunas), so I hope it to be the former .)